# How to make screen size an independent variable

Tags: screen-size

I'm working on a school project where I'm making a game of tetris. I haven't coded the entire game yet, I'm only trying to fix the field right now. In my program I have to set the screen width and height to a specific integer value and by game field is only properly aligned when the output screen is set as that same integer value. I want to make the field alignment independent of the screen size. The code where I set the screen width and height are lines 11/12 and I use the variables towards the end of the program. Here is the code that I have,

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

wstring tetromino[7];
int nFieldWidth = 12;
int nFieldHeight = 18;
unsigned char *pField = nullptr;

int nScreenWidth = 80;      // Console Screen Size X (columns)
int nScreenHeight = 30;     // Console Screen Size Y (rows)

int Rotate(int px, int py, int r)
{
    switch (r % 4)
    {
        case 0: return py * 4 + px;         // 0 degrees
        case 1: return 12 + py - (px * 4);  // 90 degrees
        case 2: return 15 - (py * 4) - px;  // 180 degrees
        case 3: return 3 - py + (px * 4);   // 270 degrees
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //Create assets
    tetromino[0].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[0].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[0].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[0].append(L"..X.");

    tetromino[1].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[1].append(L".XX.");
    tetromino[1].append(L".X..");
    tetromino[1].append(L"....");

    tetromino[2].append(L".X..");
    tetromino[2].append(L".XX.");
    tetromino[2].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[2].append(L"....");

    tetromino[3].append(L"....");
    tetromino[3].append(L".XX.");
    tetromino[3].append(L".XX.");
    tetromino[3].append(L"....");

    tetromino[4].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[4].append(L".XX.");
    tetromino[4].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[4].append(L"....");

    tetromino[5].append(L"....");
    tetromino[5].append(L".XX.");
    tetromino[5].append(L"..X.");
    tetromino[5].append(L"..X.");

    tetromino[6].append(L"....");
    tetromino[6].append(L".XX.");
    tetromino[6].append(L".X..");
    tetromino[6].append(L".X..");

    pField = new unsigned char[nFieldWidth*nFieldHeight];       //Create play field buffer
    for (int x = 0; x < nFieldWidth; x++)   //Board Boundary
        for (int y = 0; y < nFieldHeight; y++)
            pField[y*nFieldWidth + x] = (x == 0 || x == nFieldWidth - 1 || y == nFieldHeight - 1) ? 9 : 0;

    wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight];
    for (int i = 0; i < nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight; i++) screen[i] = L' ';
    HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

    bool bGameOver = false;

    while (!bGameOver)
    {
        //Draw Field
        for (int x = 0; x < nFieldWidth; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < nFieldHeight; y++)
                screen[(y + 2)*nScreenWidth + (x + 2)] = L" ABCDEFG=#"[pField[y*nFieldWidth + x]];

        //Display Frame
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
    }


    return 0;
}
```